# Why electic field at the center of a regular pentagon is zero? When charge q is situated at every corner

Tags: electrostatics

[image]
Why electic field at the center of a regular pentagon is zero? When charge q is situated at every corner

Comment: It's because of symmetry.

Comment: Have you tried computing it to see why?

Answer (score 1):

Because....
....symmetry requires that. What does this actually mean?
First you can ask yourself: If it was non-zero, in which direction would it point. Well, maybe at a corner, but there are 5 equivalent corners and non is special, so that cannot be. The same is true for the edges. So the only solution for the field that not violates the given symmetry is zero.
Actually, the zero is true for every $n$-gon with $n>1$[image: octagon].

In the image I sketched it for an octagon. The field vectors point away from the charges on the conrers (left). In the centre one has to add up the contributions of all charges (middle). Rearranging the vectors (right) leads again to an octagon. The sum is, hence, zero. Feel free to check with other regular $n$-gons.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to solve the problem with one of the easiest it to do a vector addition?
Here the diagrams are foe negative changes situated at the corners of the pentagon.

[image]